# Create a dictionary in a loop in Swift

Tags: swift, dictionary

I have a variable set of objects that I need to place in a dictionary. I'm trying to add them to the dictionary in a `for loop` but from what I'm understanding dictionaries are immutable so they need to be declared immediately. How do I create a dictionary list of items that are not predetermined?

```
var newItems = [:]

for item in self.items{
  newItems["\(item.key)"]["name"] = "A new item" 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

does not use the second value

```
var newItems : [String:String] = [:]

for i in 1..10{
  newItems[i.description] = "A new item" 
}
```

for more information `https://www.weheartswift.com/dictionaries/`

Comment: There are about 10 more properties to assign. I only listed one to demonstrate concept

Comment: if you what to the key be a string you use this newItems[item.key.description]

Comment: wait a minut i will go for mi mac for help you

Comment: check the new answer

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your original code is that dictionaries only have one key, so this construct `newItems["\(item.key)"]["name"]` is syntactically incorrect. If you had a fixed number of properties you could use a struct and put that in a dictionary. As you posed the question, though, you need to create a dictionary where the stored elements themselves are dictionaries. So, although I didn't actually put this into Xcode, it's a template for what you need to do:

```
var newItems = [:[:]]()

for item in self.items {
    var itemDict = [:]()
    for prop in whereeveryourpropertiescomefrom {
        itemDict[prop] = valueforthisproperty
    }
    newItems["\(item.key)"] = itemDict        
}
```

Of course, if your properties were initially stored in a dictionary unique to this item (equivalent of the inner loop), just store it directly into newItems.

Then, you could reference things as

```
let value = newItems["\(item.key)"]?.["property key"]
```

Notice the dictionary retrieval returns an optional you have to deal with.

Comment: This seems to be more clean than what I am currently doing. For some reason I cant declare the dictionary using [:[:]]()

Comment: Admittedly, it was a template. Probably the inner dictionary needs `[String:AnyObject]` or `[String:String]` depending on what you're doing. Then, the outer one becomes `[String: whatevertjheinneroneis]`, such as [String : `[String : AnyObject]]`

Comment: I tried [:[String:AnyObject]] but get an error "Expected expression in container literal"

Answer (score 0):

The solution was when initializing the dictionary to create another dictionary

```
var newItems: [String:[String:AnyObject]]()
```